# HTML objects and TTF font

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make a DIV or any other HTML objects wrap a TTF text completely.

My test is simple, a simple div with background color grey and some black text in it.

I try DIV, LI, A, button. Depend of the TTF font, some the text get outside the box or the box is a lot bigger. But it work great with regular web font.

Maybe there a trick with CSS or javascript. Or maybe it's a impossible task???

If this is normal, why they let us use TTF in web page if they don;t fit in basic HTML object.

Hope there a trick....

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

TTF can only be used in [certain browsers](http://caniuse.com/ttf), and in the browsers it does work in, it wouldn't be treated differently than any other text object.